# Repare jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Is there a way to repare a jupyter notebook. I can't open the notebook anymore.
I am having the following error when trying to open it.

```
Unreadable Notebook: path/to/notebook.ipynb UnicodeDecodeError('utf-8', b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x15\x18\x00\x00\x0e\x10\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\x83\xba\xacA\x00\x00\x009tEXtSoftware\x00Matplotlib version3.3.3,
....
invalid start byte'
```

The same error happens when opening the notebook in lab or notebook.
Other notebooks open without problem.

Comment: you could use a text editor to open it and remove the offending fragment. its just a JSON file, so notepad++, gedit, vim or anything else would do. I would not use the built-in Windows notepad however as it may modify line endings and cause potential issues later.

Comment: @krassowski that approach doesn't sound promising, trying to open the notebook that way bring non-readible characters as if one is trying to open a binary file.

Comment: what if you edit the file with nano? direct from terminal?

Comment: @Avatazjoe That returns non-readible characters. As when trying to open a binary file with Vim or Nano.

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3510